# iOS: iBeacons same UDID different major and minor

Tags: ios, ios8, ibeacon, udid

**Scenario:** I have 10 venues.  Each venue has a 40 - 60 iBeacons installed.  As the User enters a museum, the apps shows relevant info that's associated with each iBeacon.

**Objective:** Don't be tied down to one manufacture or use their SDKs to scan/monitor iBeacons.

**Proposed Solution:**  Have the same UDID# for all the iBeacons.  Assign the same *Major* value per museum.  Assign unique Minor value per iBeacon to distinguish between the iBeacons.

**Question:**
Since we are scanning for the same UDIDs and are not configuring the device from our app, we shouldn't need any manufacture specific SDKs.  We should be able to accomplish this by Using Apple's CoreLocation to monitor and range an iBeacon Device?

Comment: So what is your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on the manufacturer. Most of the time when you buy the beacons they are running the manufacturer's custom firmware and require you to change the configuration to "iBeacon Configuration" (Usually giving you the options to set the UUID, major, and minor fields) through the manufacturer's custom dashboard. So your correct in saying that all you need is CoreLocation framework to monitor/range beacons but you need to make sure the actual hardware is broadcasting as an "iBeacon Configuration".

Comment: Thanks.  So if the beacon is broadcasting as iBeacon, and the app knows the UDID, we can CoreLocation to range it? No manufacture SDK is required?